# Perl errors while trying to replace words in a large file

Tags: perl

I have a huge `1.1 GB` File. It contains only **1** line and `1167889705` characters. I want to replace all the occurences of "LFENT" by "\nLFENT".
I am using

> perl 5, version 18, subversion 1 (v5.18.1) built for x86_64-linux –

---

### Perl Script

```
 perl -ne 's/LFENT/\nLFENT/g; print;' queries.txt
```

---

### Sample

```
   22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 0 0 134477 0 0 0 9 LFENT_1_1 6 LFDOC1 20 documents/LFDOC1.xml 6 PERSON 12 barack obama 0 0 1 0 12 barack obama 0 0 6 LFDOC1 0 76 127 0.11599133 151 0.11042373 331 0.057491675 389 0.05621225 396 0.065223008 398 0.12416559 421 0.10331947 502 0.055213902 641 0.08908961 642 0.084330745 690 0.11456303 699 0.16876614 720 0.080576144 791 0.077269703 792 0.077503696 849 0.08224529 854 0.074629158 1028 0.11078026 1039 0.091981322 1300 0.070129424 1359 0.06072164 1390 0.05564769 1424 0.076605573 1461 0.15357952 1467 0.083702087 1583 0.069745384 1960 0.088143557 2118 0.064093992 2192 0.054430917 2304 0.089718938 2417 0.10173298 2436 0.069064997 2683 0.12296619 2700 0.068218805 2715 0.14005794 2786 0.084942013 3016 0.08474879 3113 0.083180025 3183 0.07413847 3202 0.081254445 3351 0.21241546 3587 0.061469007 3711 0.068944298 3949 0.10349752 5284 0.087500088 5775 0.092185706 5816 0.20625457 6320 0.11784423 6435 0.076852165 6794 0.094336778 6805 0.063363358 6946 0.11133534 7277 0.074097082 7588 0.12458359 7590 0.099151991 7629 0.28773388 7790 0.1194713 8137 0.11009126 8214 0.10754209 8889 0.12056628 9326 0.13841057 9701 0.25610805 9863 0.11877144 9908 0.11499001 10500 0.12205271 11917 0.11144774 12750 0.11285295 13453 0.13751692 19236 0.12948024 20390 0.12416928 20795 0.11188922 23777 0.13165452 23887 0.10065161 27644 0.1620737 73361 0.16295943 75521 0.17926371 9 LFENT_1_2 6 LFDOC1 20 documents/LFDOC1.xml 6 PERSON 5 obama 2 0 12 barack obama 5 obama 6 LFDOC1 0 76 127 0.11599133 151 0.11042373 331 0.057491675 389 0.05621225 396 0.065223008 398 0.12416559 421 0.10331947 502 0.055213902 641 0.08908961 642 0.084330745 690 0.11456303 699 0.16876614 720 0.080576144 791 0.077269703 792 0.077503696 849 0.08224529 854 0.074629158 1028 0.11078026 1039 0.091981322 1300 0.070129424 1359 0.06072164 1390 0.05564769 1424 0.076605573 1461 0.15357952 1467 0.083702087 1583 0.069745384 1960 0.088143557 2118 0.064093992 2192 0.054430917 2304 0.089718938 2417 0.10173298 2436 0.069064997 2683 0.12296619 2700 0.068218805 2715 0.14005794 2786 0.084942013 3016 0.08474879 3113 0.083180025 3183 0.07413847 3202 0.081254445 3351 0.21241546 3587 0.061469007 3711 0.068944298 3949 0.10349752 5284 0.087500088 5775 0.092185706 5816 0.20625457 6320 0.11784423 6435 0.076852165 6794 0.094336778 6805 0.063363358 6946 0.11133534 7277 0.074097082 7588 0.12458359 7590 0.099151991 7629 0.28773388 7790 0.1194713 8137 0.11009126 8214 0.10754209 8889 0.12056628 9326 0.13841057 9701 0.25610805 9863 0.11877144 9908 0.11499001 10500 0.12205271 11917 0.11144774 12750 0.11285295 13453 0.13751692 19236 0.12948024 20390 0.12416928 20795 0.11188922 23777 0.13165452 23887 0.10065161 27644 0.1620737 73361 0.16295943 75521 0.17926371 9 LFENT_1_3 6 LFDOC1 20 documents/LFDOC1.xml 4 MISC 8 american 1 0 8 american 6 LFDOC1 0 76 127 0.11599133 151 0.11042373 331 0.057491675 389 0.05621225 396 0.065223008 398 0.12416559 421 0.10331947 502 0.055213902 641 0.08908961 642 0.084330745 690 0.11456303 699 0.16876614 720 0.080576144 791 0.077269703 792 0.077503696 849 0.08224529 854 0.074629158 1028 0.11078026 1039 0.091981322 1300 0.070129424 1359 0.06072164 1390 0.05564769 1424 0.076605573 1461 0.15357952 1467 0.083702087 1583 0.069745384 1960 0.088143557 2118 0.064093992 2192 0.054430917 2304 0.089718938 2417 0.10173298 2436 0.069064997 2683 0.12296619 2700 0.068218805 2715 0.14005794 2786 0.084942013 3016 0.08474879 3113 0.083180025 3183 0.07413847 3202 0.081254445 3351 0.21241546 3587 0.061469007 3711 0.068944298 3949 0.10349752 5284 0.087500088 5775 0.092185706 5816 0.20625457 6320 0.11784423 6435 0.076852165 6794 0.094336778 6805 0.063363358 6946 0.11133534 7277 0.074097082 7588 0.12458359 7590 0.099151991 7629 0.28773388 7790 0.1194713 8137 0.11009126 8214 0.10754209 8889 0.12056628 9326 0.13841057 9701 0.25610805 9863 0.11877144 9908 0.11499001 10500 0.12205271 11917 0.11144774 12750 0.11285295 13453 0.13751692 19236
```

---

## Problem

The script will work on the sample that I posted. But when I try it on the whole line I get the following error:

```
Substitution loop at -e line 1, <> line 1.
```

Comment: What perl version are you using? (check with perl -v)

Comment: http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2014/10/msg221751.html

Comment: This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 1 (v5.18.1) built for x86_64-linux

Comment: Split your file into two or more parts (use `\n` as split point), process each individually, join them back.

Comment: @ThomasG If i remove the **-n** it doesn't print anymore

Comment: When I try to split it by using python for example. I have to load the whole "Line" again into memory. And it freezes again.

Comment: @HaniGoc use split, the unix util. takes a regex.

Comment: @raina77ow They can't split on `\n` since their entire file consists of a single line, but another character would work.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Another character that's not in `[LFENT]` :)

Comment: @HaniGoc: By the way, `perl -ne 's/LFENT/\nLFENT/g; print;' queries.txt` is generally written `perl -pe 's/LFENT/\nLFENT/g' queries.txt`

Comment: @HaniGoc remember to accept an answer (whichever suited you best) by clicking the check mark next to any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simplest to use `LFENT` as the record separator. That reduces the blocks to a more manageable size and ensures that there is no more than one `LFENT` to be replaced in each block

Command-line perl allows for setting the record separator with the `-0` modifier, but the value of the parameter must be the code point in octal of a single character, and you can't specify a string. So here you have to set it once in a `BEGIN` block

Like this

```
perl -p -e'BEGIN{$/="LFENT"} s/LFENT/\nLFENT/'
```

### output

```
22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 0 0 134477 0 0 0 9 
LFENT_1_1 6 LFDOC1 20 documents/LFDOC1.xml 6 PERSON 12 barack obama 0 0 1 0 12 barack obama 0 0 6 LFDOC1 0 76 127 0.11599133 151 0.11042373 331 0.057491675 389 0.05621225 396 0.065223008 398 0.12416559 421 0.10331947 502 0.055213902 641 0.08908961 642 0.084330745 690 0.11456303 699 0.16876614 720 0.080576144 791 0.077269703 792 0.077503696 849 0.08224529 854 0.074629158 1028 0.11078026 1039 0.091981322 1300 0.070129424 1359 0.06072164 1390 0.05564769 1424 0.076605573 1461 0.15357952 1467 0.083702087 1583 0.069745384 1960 0.088143557 2118 0.064093992 2192 0.054430917 2304 0.089718938 2417 0.10173298 2436 0.069064997 2683 0.12296619 2700 0.068218805 2715 0.14005794 2786 0.084942013 3016 0.08474879 3113 0.083180025 3183 0.07413847 3202 0.081254445 3351 0.21241546 3587 0.061469007 3711 0.068944298 3949 0.10349752 5284 0.087500088 5775 0.092185706 5816 0.20625457 6320 0.11784423 6435 0.076852165 6794 0.094336778 6805 0.063363358 6946 0.11133534 7277 0.074097082 7588 0.12458359 7590 0.099151991 7629 0.28773388 7790 0.1194713 8137 0.11009126 8214 0.10754209 8889 0.12056628 9326 0.13841057 9701 0.25610805 9863 0.11877144 9908 0.11499001 10500 0.12205271 11917 0.11144774 12750 0.11285295 13453 0.13751692 19236 0.12948024 20390 0.12416928 20795 0.11188922 23777 0.13165452 23887 0.10065161 27644 0.1620737 73361 0.16295943 75521 0.17926371 9 
LFENT_1_2 6 LFDOC1 20 documents/LFDOC1.xml 6 PERSON 5 obama 2 0 12 barack obama 5 obama 6 LFDOC1 0 76 127 0.11599133 151 0.11042373 331 0.057491675 389 0.05621225 396 0.065223008 398 0.12416559 421 0.10331947 502 0.055213902 641 0.08908961 642 0.084330745 690 0.11456303 699 0.16876614 720 0.080576144 791 0.077269703 792 0.077503696 849 0.08224529 854 0.074629158 1028 0.11078026 1039 0.091981322 1300 0.070129424 1359 0.06072164 1390 0.05564769 1424 0.076605573 1461 0.15357952 1467 0.083702087 1583 0.069745384 1960 0.088143557 2118 0.064093992 2192 0.054430917 2304 0.089718938 2417 0.10173298 2436 0.069064997 2683 0.12296619 2700 0.068218805 2715 0.14005794 2786 0.084942013 3016 0.08474879 3113 0.083180025 3183 0.07413847 3202 0.081254445 3351 0.21241546 3587 0.061469007 3711 0.068944298 3949 0.10349752 5284 0.087500088 5775 0.092185706 5816 0.20625457 6320 0.11784423 6435 0.076852165 6794 0.094336778 6805 0.063363358 6946 0.11133534 7277 0.074097082 7588 0.12458359 7590 0.099151991 7629 0.28773388 7790 0.1194713 8137 0.11009126 8214 0.10754209 8889 0.12056628 9326 0.13841057 9701 0.25610805 9863 0.11877144 9908 0.11499001 10500 0.12205271 11917 0.11144774 12750 0.11285295 13453 0.13751692 19236 0.12948024 20390 0.12416928 20795 0.11188922 23777 0.13165452 23887 0.10065161 27644 0.1620737 73361 0.16295943 75521 0.17926371 9 
LFENT_1_3 6 LFDOC1 20 documents/LFDOC1.xml 4 MISC 8 american 1 0 8 american 6 LFDOC1 0 76 127 0.11599133 151 0.11042373 331 0.057491675 389 0.05621225 396 0.065223008 398 0.12416559 421 0.10331947 502 0.055213902 641 0.08908961 642 0.084330745 690 0.11456303 699 0.16876614 720 0.080576144 791 0.077269703 792 0.077503696 849 0.08224529 854 0.074629158 1028 0.11078026 1039 0.091981322 1300 0.070129424 1359 0.06072164 1390 0.05564769 1424 0.076605573 1461 0.15357952 1467 0.083702087 1583 0.069745384 1960 0.088143557 2118 0.064093992 2192 0.054430917 2304 0.089718938 2417 0.10173298 2436 0.069064997 2683 0.12296619 2700 0.068218805 2715 0.14005794 2786 0.084942013 3016 0.08474879 3113 0.083180025 3183 0.07413847 3202 0.081254445 3351 0.21241546 3587 0.061469007 3711 0.068944298 3949 0.10349752 5284 0.087500088 5775 0.092185706 5816 0.20625457 6320 0.11784423 6435 0.076852165 6794 0.094336778 6805 0.063363358 6946 0.11133534 7277 0.074097082 7588 0.12458359 7590 0.099151991 7629 0.28773388 7790 0.1194713 8137 0.11009126 8214 0.10754209 8889 0.12056628 9326 0.13841057 9701 0.25610805 9863 0.11877144 9908 0.11499001 10500 0.12205271 11917 0.11144774 12750 0.11285295 13453 0.13751692 19236[Finished in 0.2s]
```

By the way, it is unlikely to cause a problem but `LFENT` is always preceded by a space character in your example data. You may want to remove it by using `s/\s*LFENT/\nLFENT` for your substitution

And a look-ahead might be more appropriate too `s/\s*(?=LFENT)/\n/` so that you don't have to remove and replace the unchanged part of the match

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your perl to a more current version.

This was a known bug for a long time (fixed in v5.22.0): [perl #123071: substitution loop issue with long strings](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2014/10/msg221751.html)

You can do so with the following commands (assuming you are on linux):

```
wget http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.22.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf perl-5.22.1.tar.gz
cd perl-5.22.1
./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
make
make test
make install
```

Then test it by running `$HOME/localperl/bin/perl -v` and add it to your PATH using this: `export PATH=$HOME/localperl/bin/:$PATH`.

Comment: oh you are right in your link it says   **But that will still fail in 5.18 and earlier, because it was not until 5.20 that the regular expression gained support for strings longer than 2GB.**