# Awk replacement for a multiline perl substitution operation

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I use this Perl command on to strip out chunks of a database dump. It starts at a commented line which contains the string `TABLE DATA; Schema: pgq;` and ends later with the character sequence `\.` by itself on a line. All matches are deleted.

```
perl -p0e 's/\n--[^\n]*TABLE DATA; Schema: pgq;.*?\n\\\.\n//gs'
```

This works except when processing a database dump greater than a couple of gigabytes due to a [perl bug that's been fixed in 5.22](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34595308/651980). I'm stuck on Perl 5.18 (Ubuntu 14.04) and upgrading is not an option.

I'm looking at rewriting the Perl expression using awk and the `-vRS` and `-vORS` variables and possibly a `gsub` operator, but I can't seem to find any examples for my use case. Is it something even possible with awk?

I'm using `GNU Awk 4.0.1`.

Comment: Why not installing a fresh perl in your HOME dir ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is on a server without Internet access so I have to work with what I have. It's not an option to upgrade Perl as I mentioned. I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output you'll have a better chance of getting the right answer. Include the cases that are hard to handle not just the sunny day ones. And yes, it's only software so anything's possible.

Comment: `.*?\n\\\.\n` should be `(?:(?!\n\\\.\n).)*+\n\\\.\n`. You can get around the limitation by replacing that with `(?:(?:(?!\n\\\.\n).){65535})*+(?:(?!\n\\\.\n).)*+\n\\\.\n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't you get the same effect by working linewise? This would bypass the "long string" regex bug:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^--.*TABLE DATA; Schema: pgq;/ .. ($_ eq "\\.\n")'
```

We process the input one line at a time (`-n`). We print each line unless we're in a chunk that is to be stripped.

The [`..` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) (in scalar context) keeps track of our state (whether we should skip or not). The beginning of a skippable region is marked by the condition `/^--.*TABLE DATA; Schema: pgq;/` (i.e. a regex match against the current line); the end of a skippable region is marked by `$_ eq "\\.\n"` (i.e. a line containing exactly `\.`).

Comment: Wow this seems to work. Can you comment a bit on the syntax? In my regex I had to use a non-greedy modifier after the first match was found. Your solution seems to flip the approach upside down.

Comment: @Jeff Edited. Does this help?

Comment: Kudos to **melpomene** for pointing this out, but you were using `perl -0` to read an *entire file*. (That should be `perl -0777`) When your code crashed with > 2GB files, your first thought should *not* be to search for bugs in others' code, it should be "why am I reading 2GB from a file in one pass"? There are reasons why you don't keep all data in memory all the time.

Comment: @Jeff: *"Wow this seems to work"*. For several reasons it is also likely to be rather faster than slurping gigabytes of data. Developers aren't trying to screw you over when they implement buffered I/O.